# How to differentiate password containing @ and host name starting also with @?

Tags: batch-file, scripting

I will run a batch script with username, password and host IP as parameter in this format:

**username:password@hostip**

But my password contains `@` symbol. So it outputs that the host can't be found.

For example:

```
batch.bat root:pass@q@10.120.36.65
```

How will I do this from a batch script?

Comment: This is used for FTP ? or another thing ?? if this is for FTP ==> Take a look at this ==> [How to open an FTP folder in Windows via VBScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34994285/how-to-open-an-ftp-folder-in-windows-via-vbscript?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: Is this parameter parsed by `batch.bat`? if so you need to show the code. Or is it simply fed into some command unedited? if so you need to tell us what command it is. Otherwise we can just guess...

Comment: Thanks for all your Answers. But my problem was the batch file was internally calling one more ruby file and the Regex to match it was written there.So I made changes to the ruby and it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal

for /F "tokens=1,2* delims=:@" %%a in ("%1") do (
   set "user=%%a"
   set "pass=%%b"
   set "host=%%c"
)
for /F "tokens=1* delims=@" %%a in ("%host%") do (
   if "%%b" neq "" (
      set "pass=%pass%@%%a"
      set "host=%%b"
   )
)

echo Username: "%user%"
echo Password: "%pass%"
echo HostIP:   "%host%"
```

Output examples:

```
C:\> batch.bat username:password@hostip
Username: "username"
Password: "password"
HostIP:   "hostip"

C:\> batch.bat root:pass@q@10.120.36.65
Username: "root"
Password: "pass@q"
HostIP:   "10.120.36.65"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my batch code to split the string up to user name, password and host IP address or host name:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
if "%~1" == "" goto OutputError

set "NameUser="
set "Password="
set "HostNameIP="

for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%I in ("%~1") do (
    set "NameUser=%%I"
    set "Password=%%J"
    set "HostNameIP=%%J"
)

rem Is there a colon at all in string and something after the colon?
if "%Password%" == "" goto OutputError

rem Is there at least one At sign in argument string after first colon?
if "%Password:@=%" == "%HostNameIP%" goto OutputError

rem Get host name/IP which is the string after last At sign.
rem The argument string should not end with an At sign.
:GetHostNameIP
set "HostNameIP=%HostNameIP:*@=%"
if "%HostNameIP%" == "" goto OutputError
if not "%HostNameIP:@=%" == "%HostNameIP%" goto GetHostNameIP

rem Get password which is the string between first colon and last
rem At sign which is here the password string with all (hopefully
rem only one) @HostNameIP removed from password string.
set "Password=!Password:@%HostNameIP%=!"

rem Is there a password in argument string?
if "%Password%" == "" goto OutputError

echo The user name is: %NameUser%
echo The password is:  %Password%
echo Host name/IP is:  %HostNameIP%
goto EndBatch

:OutputError
echo.
echo ERROR: username:password@host not specified correct.

:EndBatch
echo.
endlocal
pause
```

The password string can have 1 or even more At signs included. There is most likely always only 1 `@` as the email address is used as password although this is not good for a password.

Of course it would be much easier to require that the batch file is executed with 3 separate arguments being user name, password and host IP address as then it would not be necessary to split up a single argument string into 3 separate strings.

Further I suppose `username:password@hostip` is needed for a console application executed from within the batch file. Most of this console applications support also another variant of specifying user name, password and host IP address with separated strings at least for the password in comparison to this concatenated variant. It would be definitely a good idea to call the console application with the 3 strings specified separately if supported by the console application.

**Note**: `USERNAME` is a predefined environment variable which should not be used for this batch file which is the reason for using `NameUser`.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?` ... explains `%~1` (first argument string without surrounding double quotes)
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `pause /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`