# Copying a file to an FTP server using VBScript without using commercial third party FTP components

Tags: vbscript, ftp, upload, file-copying

I am trying to prepare a VB script that can copy a file to a server for my client, cant' use expensive third party FTP component in the script.

Maybe there is a problem with the line "objFTP.CopyHere objItem, copyType" but I have no idea how to sort this out. Any idea?

Here is my code:

```
Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

path = "D:\test\"

FTPUpload(path)
Sub FTPUpload(path)

'On Error Resume Next

Const copyType = 16

'FTP Wait Time in ms
waitTime = 80000


FTPUser = "xxxxx"
FTPPass = "xxxxxx"
FTPHost = "xxxx.xxx"
FTPDir = "/public_html/testfolder/"

strFTP = "ftp://" & FTPUser & ":" & FTPPass & "@" & FTPHost & FTPDir

Set objFTP = oShell.NameSpace(strFTP)
MsgBox  strFTP
'Upload single file       
ufile = path & "bappy.txt"
If objFSO.FileExists(ufile) Then
Set objFile = objFSO.getFile(ufile)
strParent = objFile.ParentFolder
Set objFolder = oShell.NameSpace(strParent)
Set objItem = objFolder.ParseName(objFile.Name)
Wscript.Echo "Uploading file " & objItem.Name & " to " & strFTP
objFTP.CopyHere objItem, copyType

End If

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
Wscript.Echo "Error: " & Err.Description
End If

'Wait for upload
Wscript.Sleep waitTime

End Sub
```

Comment: You are using Windows Explorer object. What happens when you do it manually in Windows Explorer. Consider adding the FTP site in *This PC* (right click - *Add Network Location*) and access it through this path.

Comment: I want to build a script that can upload a file to the server by ftp or any means. So manual process is not an option though I can use available FTP clients if I had to do it manually.

Comment: Nothing stops you adding it programmatically. I've used this to download from Microsoft's FTP server. As FTP servers are generally implemented by HTTP servers https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms763706(v=vs.85).aspx.

Comment: You can always shell out to ftp.exe. `CreateObject("WScript.Shell").run """ftp.exe"" -s:""ftpscript.txt"" 127.0.0.1"` See many options.

Comment: [How to open an FTP folder in Windows via VBScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34994285/how-to-open-an-ftp-folder-in-windows-via-vbscript?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: [FTP Upload and FTP Download with VBScript](http://naterice.com/ftp-upload-and-ftp-download-with-vbscript/)