# Using special characters in batch strings

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file which download a file via ftp. The structure is the following:

```
dir ftp://user:password@10.01.01.01//dir_to_file
```

The problem I have is that the password is something like: @h%h@Z3$

How can I write that in a batch file as a string? I tried using "@h%h@Z3$" o "@h%h@Z3$" without any luck.

Comment: First of all `dir` doesn't download anything, in provides a `dir`ectory listing. Secondly, in a batch file, the percent character, `%`, is special. It will therefore need to be escaped with another `%` character, for example `@h%%h@Z3$`

Comment: Try with this and tell me if it works or not ? [How to open an FTP folder in Windows via VBScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34994285/how-to-open-an-ftp-folder-in-windows-via-vbscript)

Comment: @Compo sorry, "dir" here means directory it was a string .\Directory\Directory..

Comment: …and what happens when you escape the percent character, using `@h%%h@Z3$`? as was the main point of my comment!